# Cannot appendTo() content that was once in a variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables, append

I am working on small gallery plug-in. The goal is for a person to create a series of un-ordered lists containing images, and wrap those in a div which has the class gallery. This would be the setup and my script would grab the contents of .gallery and store them in a variable, add in some new html elements to .gallery, and then allow my styling and gallery scripts to take over.

here is how I am grabbing and restructuring the html:

```
 var content = $("#gallery").html();

    $("#gallery").html("<div id='galleryInner'><div id='galleryTrack'>"+content+"</div>   
<div class='mask' id='leftMask'><div class='btn' id='lBtn'><img src='images/arrowL.png'> 
</div></div><div class='mask' id='rightMask'><div class='btn' id='rBtn'><img 
src='images/arrowR.png'></div></div></div></div>");
```

After things are set up in this way my script can manipulate some aspects this html structure but other aspects fail.

for instance:

```
function moveLeft() {
   $('#galleryTrack ul:first-child').animate({
       width: 0,
     }, 250, function() {
   $("#galleryTrack ul:first-child").appendTo($("#galleryTrack"));
   $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").css("width", w);
     });         
}
```

The animation is working, but the appendTo() and css() are not.

It works fine if it is all static, it is only when I recreate the content with javascript that it breaks.

Any ideas why?

*EDIT***

Ok here is the full code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = 1;
    var count = 0;
    var w = $("#galleryTrack ul:first-child").width();
    var nh = 0;
    var h = 0;
    var timer = null;
    var msg = $("#msg");
    var content = $("#gallery").html();

    $("#gallery").html("<div id='galleryInner'><div id='galleryTrack'>"+content+"</div></div><div class='mask' id='leftMask'><div class='btn' id='lBtn' style='display: none;'><img src='images/arrowL.png'></div></div><div class='mask' id='rightMask'><div class='btn' id='rBtn' style='display: none;'><img src='images/arrowR.png'></div></div>");

   $('#rBtn').click(function(){
       clearTimeout(timer); 
       timer = setTimeout(moveLeft, 250);
   }); 

    $('#lBtn').click(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer); 
      timer = setTimeout(moveRight, 250);
    }); 

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
         clearTimeout(timer); 
         timer = setTimeout(moveLeft, 250);
      }
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(moveRight, 250);
      }
    });

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#galleryTrack ul:first-child').animate({
            width: 0,
        }, 250, function() {
            $("#galleryTrack ul:first-child").appendTo($("#galleryTrack"));
            $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").css("width", w);
        });         
    }

    function moveRight() {
        $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").css("width", "0");
        $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").prependTo($("#galleryTrack"));
        $('#galleryTrack ul:first-child').animate({
            width: w,
        }, 250);
     }                                


     $("#gallery").mouseover(function(e) { 
         if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
              $("#lBtn").fadeIn(300);
              $("#rBtn").fadeOut(300);
         } else {
              $("#rBtn").fadeIn(300);
              $("#lBtn").fadeOut(300);     
         }
     });

     $("#gallery").hover(function() {
     }, function() {
         $(".btn").fadeOut(300);     
     });  

  });
```

***EDIT... AGAIN***

Ok so it seems like it is the animation in the function moveRight() that is actually the problem:

```
 function moveRight() {
             $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").css("width", "0");
             $("#galleryTrack ul:last-child").prependTo($("#galleryTrack"));
             $('#galleryTrack ul:first-child').animate({
                  width: w,
             }, 250);
           }
```

Comment: not give your code in parts instead paste your full jquery code!

Comment: ok I got it, var w just needed to be declared after the $("#gallery").html(...) line